# Python Kivy - underline not working in label

Tags: python, label, kivy

I know this question has been asked before ([Underline text in a Label in Kivy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23128123/underline-text-in-a-label-in-kivy/23128651#23128651)) and it is quite an old question but I was really wondering if there is a way to underline text in label's in Kivy?
The only suggested solution I've found online is using a python script extended_markup.py. But this does not work and is riddled with problems due to updates in Kivy. 
I've tried messing around myself but underline even seems to be removed from markup in the kivy source code...even though the documentation talks about underline!
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This functionality has been added in the development version of Kivy 1.9.2-dev. The instructions to update to the development version vary by platform: https://kivy.org/docs/installation/installation.html

You can set underline on a `Label` widget to underline the text:

```
Label:
    text: 'underline this!'
    underline: True
```

You can also use markup:

```
Label:
    text: 'underline [u]this![/u]'
    markup: True
```

However, underline is not supported by all text providers. In particular, the SDL2 text provider does support it while the pygame and PIL providers do not.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have tried that method and it doesn't work. I looked around to get the SDL2 provider to work and nada. How do I get it to work so I can have underline render?

Comment: @Hazey Sorry, underline has been added in the development version, but is not in the latest release version (1.9.1). I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thank you so much Ryan! It worked. This has been my headache for weeks!