# Possible bug in Kivy markup

Tags: kivy

I have a kivy label and I wish to underline the text. The bold, colour and italic tags work correctly, but I seem to have a problem with underline and strikethrough. Is this a bug? I seem to have the correct syntax.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label

class Hello(App):
    def build(self):
        lbl = Label(text='[b]One[/b] [u]two[/u] [i]three[/i] [color=ff0000]four[/color] [s]five[/s]', markup=True)
    return  lbl

Hello().run()
```

I am using the SDL2 text provider and Kivy 1.9.1[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you using the SDL2 text provider? And Kivy 1.9.1?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Underline text in a Label in Kivy?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23128123/underline-text-in-a-label-in-kivy)

Comment: No, I don't think so. I understand the syntax, but it appears not to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently it's not implemented in your version yet: https://github.com/kivy/kivy/issues/4059

Comment: Thank you Nykakin. However it's annoying because kivy doesn't even remove the tags ([u]) and so you cannot 'pre-prepare' your text ready for the implementation.

Comment: Is it fixed in 1.92?

Comment: There isn't a stable 1.9.2 version yet, only the development version. But yes, I believe it should be fixed in this version. Haven't tested it myself, though.